# PowerShell Module Manifest FileList property - specifically what does it do?

Tags: powershell-module

So I am trying to refine my PowerShell module skills.
There is a parameter in the module manifest (.psd1) called 'FileList'.
It has the helpful documentation

```
# List of all files packaged with this module
FileList = @()
```

So, I have a module that contains a few .psm1 files.  Perfect! (I thought).  Perhaps I should list these files there?

However, the files I do list in FileList seem to get resolved to full path names when the module is imported, but none of the functions they contain are available?

Does this mean I need to list the .psm1 files in two places?
I had been listing them in NestedModules, which did import the functions, but I'm unsure if this is right?

Does anyone have any insight on *specifically* what FileList does and does not do, and how it should be used with a PowerShell module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This parameter isn't used at the moment by PowerShell.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-module-manifest):

> List of all files packaged with this module. As with ModuleList, FileList is to assist you as an inventory list, and is not otherwise processed.

You can give a full list of files included. But you still have to use the NestedModules parameter (depending on the structure of your module), because it has a different purpose.